# Swift guard statement usage

Tags: swift2, guard-statement

Depending on my understanding of `guard` statement in swift I am doing the following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let identifier = "identifier"
    let dequeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier)

    guard let cell = dequeCell else
    {
        // The following line gives error saying: Variable declared in 'guard'condition is not usable in its body
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"

    return cell
}
```

I just want to understand is can we create a variable in `guard` statement and access it in rest of the function? or are the guard statements intended to immediately return or throw exceptions?

Or I am completely misunderstanding the usage of `guard` statement?

Comment: No the `guard` statement is supposed to cause the method to return or throw if it's false.

Comment: Use the newer `dequeue...` method (the one that expects the index path as the second argument): it will allocate the cell for you if none is available in the reuse pool, and never returns `nil`. Then, force-cast into your custom cell subclass (this should never fail if you registered class/identifier properly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation describes it pretty well

> If the `guard` statement’s condition is met, code execution continues
>   after the `guard` statement’s closing brace. Any variables or constants
>   that were assigned values using an optional binding as part of the
>   condition are available for the rest of the code block that the `guard`
>   statement appears in.
>
> If that condition is not met, the code inside the else branch is
>   executed. **That branch must transfer control to exit the code block in
>   which the `guard` statement appears. It can do this with a control
>   transfer statement such as return, break, continue, or throw, or it
>   can call a function or method that doesn’t return, such as
>   fatalError()**.

In your particular case you don't need the guard statement at all, since the recommended method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` returns always a non-optional type.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let identifier = "identifier"
    let dequeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
}
```